# Generating new columns with subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables, imports and importrows. importrows contains all of the information regarding each entry in an import. I'm assuming this is possible through a subquery.

**importrows**

```
import_id  | status

0001       | success

0001       | error

0001       | success

0001       | error

0002       | success

0003       | success

0001       | success

0001       | success

0001       | error

0003       | error
```

**imports**

```
import_id      |  created
    
    0001       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53
    
    0002       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53
    
    0003       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53
```

I'd like to add these two tables together to form something like this:

```
import_id      |  created             | success | error
    
    0001       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53  |    4    |   3
    
    0002       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53  |    1    |   0
     
    0003       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53  |    1    |   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need JOIN and GROUP BY operations

```
select
  i.import_id,
  i.created,
  s.success,
  e.error
from 
  imports i
join
  (select import_id, count(*) as success from importrows where status='success' group by import_id) s on s.import_id=i.import_id
join
  (select import_id, count(*) as error from importrows where status='error' group by import_id) e on e.import_id=i.import_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.import_id,i.created,s.success,e.error from imports i left join (select import_id, count(*) as success from importrows where status='success' group by import_id) s on s.import_id=i.import_id left join (select import_id, count(*) as error from importrows where status='error' group by import_id) e on e.import_id=i.import_id
```

Do a **left join and group by**, that way if you do not have a 'success' or 'error' for a particular import, it is still displayed.